# Looking for command line ftp client (linux)

Tags: command-line, ftp, download

I am looking to batch download a large number of files (>800). I have a text file with the list of all the filenames. These filenames are then used to derive the URL from which they can be downloaded. I had been parsing through the file with a python script, using subprocess to wget the files.

```
wget ftp://ftp.name.of.site/filename-prefix/filename/filename+suffix
```

However for reasons unknown to me, wget is failing to properly connect. I wanted to know if I could essentially use an ftp program that would work in a similar manner, i.e. no login and stay within the commandline.

Edit:
What's in my text file:

```
ERS032033
ERS032214
ERS032234
ERS032223
ERS032218
```

The ERS### act as the prefix. The whole thing is the filename. The final file (i.e. filename+suffix) would look something like: ERS032033_1.fastq.gz

Submitting the correct url is not the problem.

Comment: can you post a redacted version of your text file?

Comment: I posted the redacted version of the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Python, I suggest dropping the subprocess approach and using the `urllib` module instead:

```
import urllib
handle = urllib.urlopen('ftp://ftp.name.of.site/filename-prefix/filename/filename+suffix')
print handle.read()
handle.close()
```

Assuming you are using Python 2 ([urllib.request](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) for Python 3)

If you simply need batch download, [urllib.urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) is a cleaner approach.

Comment: Eliminated FTP script part of the answer for conciseness :)